# NotesViewColumn check if Total option is enabled

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

how can I check if something is selected there? I need at least 'fact': selected or not (and would be nice to know how to read real settings).

I looked into NotesViewColumn and did not find anything there, maybe it's undocumented feature :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DXL. The DXL schema for view columns includes an attribute that represents the selected option for the totals.

I.e. set up a NotesNoteCollection object that includes the view design note. Use NotesSession.CreateDXLExporter to get a NotesDXLExporter and process the NotesNoteCollection, parsing the XML to locate the column and get the value for the totals attribute.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and I'm sure it will work, however I'm looking for something more simple, i.e. 'native' flag or so.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way that would be simpler. (The info has got to be there if you get the NotesNoteCollection and access the view note as a document and read the items. I've never looked at it, so that's all I can say - but I'm sure you can figure it out with a little experimentation, toggling the totals option on and off and seeing what changes. That would be less code, but not really simpler.)